# Why do we need inodes for files and directories?

Tags: filesystems

I don't really understand why do we need Index nodes. After searching for manuals I learned that it stores some meta data about files or directories.
However isn't that already what a directory does? (storing entries for files which hold it's size ,name etc..)

Comment: You don't need anything -- feel free to design a filesystem without separate inodes (eg. `iso9660` doesn't have any inodes, the inode numbers are made up by the fs driver -- iirc on BSD they were the actual _offsets_ of the 1st block of the file). And no, directories don't hold any file metadata on Unix: they're just lists of names and inode numbers (on modern Linux filesystems, they also hold the file type as a single byte, but nothing like permissions, times, size, list of blocks, etc)

Comment: @mosvy Using the first block address as inode number only works for `iso9660` if you used a ` mkisofs` from after September 2006 to create the filesystem, since other programs do not have a strategy for zero sized files. BTW: POSIX requires inode numbers to identify files, so you cannot avoid them without forcing various programs to fail to check whether two files are identical.

Comment: I don't really keep up with you guys I'm a Linux beginner 
so the reason that there is an inode is the file system which can be changed so why don't just use the directories for all kinds of meta data instead of scattering them between directories and inodes

Comment: Directories only map names to inodes, and each inode can have several names.  Inodes are also used for files which have been deleted but are still open and other kinds of nameless files.

Comment: @schily right, but you can make up a number which uniquely identify a file (on a per-filesystem basis).

Comment: @MahmoudSalah the separation of inodes and directory-entries (hard-links) is essential if you want to be able to implement an atomic `rename(2)` operation. Of course, you can simply not implement it, as they did in the plan9 filesystems and their 9p protocol ;-)

Comment: @mosvy so in plan9 OS they can't rename files because they don't implement this feature?

Comment: They can rename it, just as you can `mv(1)` a file between two separate filesystems on Unix, but not atomically, as the `rename(2)` system call does. Basically, if you want to copy a file from `dirA` to `dirB`, both on the same (remote) 9p filesystem, you have to copy the data twice back-and-forth.

Comment: @mosvy, doesn't atomic rename between two directories already involve copying (moving) the directory entry while making sure it's only visible (to userspace) at only one of the directories at any given point of time? Wouldn't that be pretty much the same even if the directory entry contained the inode data too? You'd just have a bit more data to move around.

Comment: @ilkkachu nope, both the source and the destination dir entries can be visible at the same time, as already mentioned in the `rename(2)` manpage. But when the new dir entry (the destination file) already exists, the userland should see either the new or the old file, never something in between the two. I think that difficult to implement without a separation between inodes and dir entries.

Answer (score 3):

It is just the way that it is implemented.

## Try setting the mode of some directories

Set one to be readable, but not crossable: `ug=r`. You will see filenames but no mode, file-size, etc.

Set one to be crossable, but not readable: `ug=x`. You will not be able to see the names, but if you know a name then you will be able to get the mode, file-size, etc.

## Why

Keeping the meta-data out of the directory structure (so it is just names), probably makes it faster. There is no need to handle large amounts of data, that is not needed. Then when it is needed, it can be read.

Every inode can have between zero and many names (possibly in different directories). It will have zero names if its name is removed, but the file is still open by a process. It may also have multiple names.

It makes rename easier to implement: Create a new directory-entry (name) for the inode (possibly in a different directory), then remove the old directory-entry (name).

In older file-systems, a directory had an entry `..` that pointed to the inode of the parent directory. Allowing multiple names for a single file (a directory is a type of file) was essential for this. Not duplicating the inode, was a good thing (no possibility of inconsistency, less waste). On modern file-systems (e.g. ext3, ext4), this is (so I have heard) simulated.

Comment: I'm wondering if all the modern filesystems are designed in that way, maybe some filesystems really store metadata in a directory entry instead of introducing the "inode" concept?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 mosvy says that iso9660 has no inodes. So, I guess, only one directory entry per file (or different permissions on each entry: I was wanting that once. (When using suid)).

Answer (score 0):

"inode", wikipedia:

> Each inode stores the attributes **and disk block locations** of the
>   object's data

(location is what matters, not size)

> **Directories are lists of names assigned to inodes**. A directory contains an entry for itself, its parent, and each of its children.

When the object is a regular file, it is a leaf and contains just data. A dir's data is *another* list of files, including more dirs, which themselves contain lists etc.

There is a practical (space,speed,robustness) side to this all. ReiserFS seems to have no explicit inodes:

> Some Unix-style file systems such as ReiserFS omit an inode table, but
>   **must store equivalent data** in order to provide equivalent
>   capabilities. The data **may be called stat data**, in reference to the
>   stat system call that provides the data to programs.

---

I made a one-liner to illustrate; I ran it from /sys. Sysfs's top inode is "1" (as is proc's - they are both *mounted*; "/" has "2", this shows up as "2 .." in `ls -a DOT`)

```
for dir in . block bus; do echo -n "---[$dir]"; command ls -ali $dir | sed -E 's/( *\w ).*( \w*)/\1\2/' |head -5; done |sed "s/total .*/---/"
```

It lists the first four entries from a dir and two subirs, showing only inode and name (`ls -ali` with only first and last field).

```
---[.]---
   1  .
   2  ..
3321  block
   8  bus
---[block]---
 3321  .
    1  ..
62233  ../devices/virtual/block/loop0
62347  ../devices/virtual/block/loop1
---[bus]---
    8  .
    1  ..
25390  ac97
 3573  acpi
```

Flattened out e.g. for a normal DB table with `name`, `id` and **`parent_id`** this amounts to the same:

```
"/"   2  2
sys   1  2
bus   8  1 
block 3321 1
ac97 25390 8
```

File (or whatever entry) "ac97" has parentid=8. so it is belongs to "bus". (this I did with my fingers)

Technically a second "ac97" in the same dir (parentid) would be ok, as long as it gets a unique id. That would be the opposite of a hard link; a pathname would not be enough, you would have to say `/sys/bus/ac97 with inode xy`. Nobody wants that, so you get "File exists", or as `man 2 mkdir` nicely explains:

```
EEXIST pathname already exists (not necessarily as a directory).
  This includes the case where pathname is a symbolic link, dangling or not
```

...because even a dead link has (is?) a direntry.

---

A directory, just like a file, has to be able to grow on a different block. The hierarchy splits up the data for the users *and* the system. Filenames are for users. Inodes (inode-numbers) for the sysem. Hard links are how users also work with the real file, and not just the one name for it.

The inodes are the glue between the users' dir structure and the filesystem's data on blocks.

In the classical sense ("index" offset / outsourced metadata) they are not needed.

---

article "btrfs" has under "File System Tree":

> Within each directory, directory entries appear as directory items,
>   who[se right-hand key values] are a [CRC32C hash of their]
>   **filename**. Their data is a **location** key, or the key of the **inode item** it points to. Directory items together can thus act as an
>   index for path-to-inode lookups

---

article tree, disambiguate first:

> A tree data structure can be defined **recursively** as a **collection of
>   nodes** (starting at a root node), where each node is a data structure
>   consisting of a value, together with **a list of references to nodes**
>   (the "children"), with the constraints that no reference is
>   duplicated, and none points to the root.

You are *not* asking what the "i" stands for in front of NODE. Are you?

---

article "linked list", "Speeding up search"

> Another common approach is to **"index"** a linked list using a more
>   efficient **external data structure**. For example, one can build a
>   **red-black tree** or hash table whose elements are references to the
>   linked list **nodes**. Multiple such indexes can be built on a single
>   list. The disadvantage is that these indexes may need to be updated
>   each time a node is added or removed (or at least, before that index
>   is used again).

No wonder the "i" stands for not much in "inode", just the dry "index".